# Saving a select count(*) value to a variable in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have `Leave Entries` table like this:

```
emp_id   LeaveTypeSName    LeaveStatus   FromDate            ToDate
----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1            CL             Full Day      21/07/2014       21/07/2014
 1            SL             Half Day      21/07/2014       21/07/2014
 1            CL             Full Day      21/07/2014       21/07/2014
 1            SL             Full Day      21/07/2014       21/07/2014
 1            CL             Half Day      21/07/2014       21/07/2014
 1            CL             Full Day      21/07/2014       24/07/2014
```

I am trying get result like this...

```
 CL_count      SL_count
 -----------------------
    6.5           1.5
```

My SQL query is

```
SELECT     
   no_dyas = SUM( DATEDIFF(d, FromDate, ToDate)),
   CL_COUNT = SUM(CASE WHEN LeaveTypeSName='CL' AND LeaveStatus='FullDay'  THEN 1 WHEN LeaveTypeSName='CL' AND LeaveStatus='HalfDay' THEN 0.5  END),
   SL_COUNT = SUM(CASE WHEN LeaveTypeSName='SL' AND LeaveStatus='FullDay' THEN 1 WHEN LeaveTypeSName='SL' AND LeaveStatus='HalfDay' THEN 0.5  END),
   FH_COUNT = SUM(CASE WHEN LeaveTypeSName='FH' AND LeaveStatus='FullDay' THEN 1 WHEN  LeaveTypeSName='FH' AND LeaveStatus='HalfDay' THEN 0.5  END),
   LOP_COUNT = SUM(CASE WHEN LeaveTypeSName='LOP' AND LeaveStatus='FullDay' THEN 1 WHEN LeaveTypeSName='LOP' AND LeaveStatus='HalfDay' THEN 0.5  END)   
FROM 
   LeaveEntries 
WHERE
   EmployeeCode = '1'
```

Please help me.....

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: here i am only getting count...like CL=4 and SL=2

Comment: Try using 1.0 instead of 1. Also add else part (ELSE 0.0).

Comment: Are you getting CL=4 or CL=6.5? What is the actual business logic to calculate these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try:

```
select 
   LeaveTypeSName,
   SUM(case when LeaveStatus='Full Day' then 1 else 0.5 end)
From 
   LeaveEntries 
where emp_id=1
group by LeaveTypeSName
```

To get the sum of leave days, try:

```
select LeaveTypeSName,
  SUM(case when LeaveStatus='Full Day' then DATEDIFF(day, FromDate, ToDate)+1 else 0.5 end)
From 
  LeaveEntries 
where emp_id=1
group by LeaveTypeSName
```

Comment: it should also include the  Leaves No ..for a eg...in last row in theleave entries it shows that number of CL is 4

Comment: @DileepKumar Please add the same in expected output.

Comment: i want LeaveTypesName count.

Comment: If you want to add *LeaveTypesName count* then add `COUNT(*)` to the select statement

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me!!!

```
SELECT     
  no_dyas = SUM( DATEDIFF(d, FromDate, ToDate)),
  CL_COUNT = SUM(CASE WHEN LeaveTypeSName='CL' AND LeaveStatus='Full Day'  THEN 1 WHEN LeaveTypeSName='CL' AND LeaveStatus='Half Day' THEN 0.5  END),
  SL_COUNT = SUM(CASE WHEN LeaveTypeSName='SL' AND LeaveStatus='Full Day' THEN 1 WHEN LeaveTypeSName='SL' AND LeaveStatus='Half Day' THEN 0.5  END),
  FH_COUNT =SUM(CASE WHEN LeaveTypeSName='FH' AND LeaveStatus='Full Day' THEN 1 WHEN  LeaveTypeSName='FH' AND LeaveStatus='Half Day' THEN 0.5  END),
  LOP_COUNT =SUM(CASE WHEN LeaveTypeSName='LOP' AND LeaveStatus='Full Day' THEN 1 WHEN LeaveTypeSName='LOP' AND LeaveStatus='Half Day' THEN 0.5  END)   
FROM 
  Leave_Entries 
WHERE    emp_id = 1
```

it's result is true... 3.5 and 1.5
I just changed the 'HalfDay' to 'Half Day' And 'FullDay' to 'Full Day' according to your data in your query and done...

Comment: This doen't regard the timespan (FromDate, ToDate)

Comment: yes but isn't important, you can add it and it will work, it worked for me correctly without any problem, (my post edited)

Comment: But the result should be 6.5 and 1.5, like described by Dileep.